# I try to correct this error but I failed what is the error in this program?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
WEIGHT_NUM NUMBER:= &WEIGHT_NUM1;
WEIGHT_TYPE VARCHAR2 :=' &WEIGHT_TYPE';
BEGIN
IF WEIGHT_TYPE='kb'  THEN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YOU ENTERED KB...CONVERT TO LB='||WEIGHT_NUM/0.45) ;
ELSIF WEIGHT_TYPE='lb'  THEN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YOU ENTERED LB...CONVERT TO KG='||WEIGHT_NUM*0.45) ;
END IF;
END;
/
```

this program the user enter his weight(WEIGHT_SIZE) in kilogram OR pound and if the use enter his weight in kilogram 'kb' the program coverts kilogram to pound or if the user enter  his weight in pound 'lb' the program coverts  pound to kilogram  but this program show an error what is the solution to fix this error ?

Comment: Please read [ask] to see some examples of good and bad titles.

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR2 datatype has to have its size. Also, it probably wouldn't harm if you rounded result of arithmetic operations:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    WEIGHT_NUM  NUMBER:= &WEIGHT_NUM1;
  3    WEIGHT_TYPE VARCHAR2(2) := '&WEIGHT_TYPE';
  4  BEGIN
  5    IF WEIGHT_TYPE = 'kb'  THEN
  6       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YOU ENTERED KB...CONVERT TO LB='|| round(WEIGHT_NUM/0.45, 2)) ;
  7    ELSIF WEIGHT_TYPE = 'lb'  THEN
  8      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YOU ENTERED LB...CONVERT TO KG='|| round(WEIGHT_NUM*0.45, 2)) ;
  9    END IF;
 10  END;
 11  /
Enter value for weight_num1: 10
Enter value for weight_type: kb
YOU ENTERED KB...CONVERT TO LB=22.22

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Whey you add round()

Comment: If l do this( weight_type varchar2(2) :=&weight_type ) why show an error?

Comment: I wouldn't know; it doesn't show any error for me (as demonstrated). Did you run that piece of code in some GUI tool? If so, use a bind variable (instead of substitution one), i.e. `:weight_type` instead of `&weight_type`.